# What is the order of operations in Java?

Tags: java, return

I have the following simple Java code and I know that the output is `baedc`

```
public class Main {
    public static String c(){
        System.out.print("b");
        return "e";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String c = "c";
        String d = "d";
        System.out.print(("a"+c())+((d)+"c"));
    } 
}
```

My question is, why doesn't it start with `a` since we print `"a"` before executing `c()` ? and if it executes `c()` first, then why not `beadc` ?

Comment: You don't print "a" before executing c(). That would only be true if you had multiple print statements in your main method.

Comment: Then why isn't it the result of `c()` and then a ? instead it's a part of c() then a then what c() returns again.

Comment: `we print "a" before executing c()`, no we don't the return value of the call `c()`has to be concatenated along with `((d)+"c")` for the argument to `println()` to have a value.

Comment: I guess it wasn’t you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429837/result-of-adding-string-with-a-function-at-println

Comment: Maybe you would see clearer what happens if you used `println` to print in a new line. Then you could see clearly that printing happens only twice in that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All function calls being passed as parameters into a function must execute before the function call, because the encompassing function must know what those functions return before executing.

Comment: Very poorly expressed. Try again.

Answer (score 9):

> we print `"a"` before executing `c()`

That is incorrect: we use `"a"` in a string concatenation expression before calling `c()`, we do not *print* it until after the string construction is completed.

That is why `"b"`, a side effect of calling `c()`, gets printed ahead of `"a"`, which is the first character in the string constructed by the concatenation expression `("a"+c())+((d)+"c")`.